# Get device screen resolution

Tags: unity-game-engine, mobile, screen, resolution

I want to get device screen resolution in **unity**.
I used `Screen.currentResolution.height/width` and `Screen.height/width`.  On Samsung galaxy s6 they returned **1920:1080**(must be 2560:1440).
I tested on other devices and **they all shows 1920:1080**.

please tell me the right way to get the resolution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Screen.height/width** worked right, problem was with my phone

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Display class](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Display.html) `Display.main.systemHeight` and `Display.main.systemWidth` it works for both PC and mobile.